# Django. runserver: “ Not Found: / ”

Tags: django

Последовательность действий по документации Django:
`django-admin startproject mysite` - 
`python manage.py migrate` - 
`python manage.py runserver`
Сервер запускается, но получаю сообщение:

> Not Found: /

Ничего не менял. Почему возникает эта проблема и как от этого избавиться?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы создаете новый проект, в `urls.py` есть только `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` соответственно у вас будет доступна только страница `/admin`.
Чтобы добавить другие url в ваш проект, нужно записать их в `urls.py` и создать для них обработчик во `views.py`

Comment: Но ведь вроде джанга должна по index.html отдавать [какой-нибудь hello world](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/images/Django/HelloWorld/BrowserDjango.png)? Или с какой-то новой версии уже убрали?

Comment: @andreymal он и отдает эту страницу но сервер пишет `Not Found: /`